# C code from gcc to Visual Studio Express 2010

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, gcc, struct

I'm trying to move some code I have written and compiled succesfully with gcc under Visual Studio Express 2010.

I have the following header file.

```
#ifndef _SYMTAB_H_
#define _SYMTAB_H_

#define NHASH 997

typedef enum {NOTYPE, INTTYPE, DOUBLETYPE, STRINGTYPE} SYMBOLTYPE;

typedef union {
    int intvalue;
    double doublevalue;
    char *stringvalue;
} SYMBOLVALUE;

typedef struct {
    SYMBOLTYPE type;
    char *name;
    SYMBOLVALUE value;
} SYMBOL;

void initSymbolTable(void);
SYMBOL *lookup(char *sym);
SYMBOL *addIntSymbol(char *name, int value);
SYMBOL *addDoubleSymbol(char *name, double value);
SYMBOL *addStringSymbol(char *name, char *value);
char *getSymbolName(SYMBOL *sym);
int getIntSymbolValue(SYMBOL *sym);
double getDoubleSymbolValue(SYMBOL *sym);
char *getStringSymbolValue(SYMBOL *sym);
void printSymbolTable(void);

#endif
```

If I write a piece of code using that header file such as:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    initSymbolTable();

    printSymbolTable();

    SYMBOL *intSymbol = addIntSymbol("pippo", 10);

    printSymbolTable();

    printf("All tests successfull\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I get the followin error:

error C2275: 'SYMBOL': illegal use of this type as an expression

which is descrideb here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76c9k4ah(v=vs.71).aspx

Anyway I don'tunderstand what's wrong with that.
I have also set the "Compile As" property to "Compile as C Code" in the prject properties under C/C++->Advanced. Moreover all files are saved as *.c and *.h.

Comment: MSVC++ is not a C compiler, because it doesn't implement the C99 standard; It fails to compile valid C code that uses features added by the C99 standard (which was ratified in 1999; over ten years ago). The solution: Don't use a C++ compiler to compile C code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't declare a variable mid-function in the version of C that Visual Studio supports.  You need do declare it at the top:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    SYMBOL *intSymbol;

    initSymbolTable();

    printSymbolTable();

    intSymbol = addIntSymbol("pippo", 10);
    ...
```

Comment: It was made legal in C99, but MS only supports C89 which does not allow it.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can right-click the .c file that throws an error in Solution Explorer, go to C/C++ -> Advanced and set Compile As to compile as C++ code. That way you don't need to edit your sources.

Comment: That's correct and it only complains about strdup since it is deprecated...anyway I need pure C code. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @salvo: not sure what you mean by `pure C code`. Your code will remain pure C. If you mean the generated binary code, there shouldn't be any substancial difference and you're only compiling for Windows anyway.

Comment: @RichieHindle: could you give me an example of valid C code that will behave differently or will be invalid if interpreted as C++? I'm sure there are such examples, but can't think of any.

Comment: `X *x = malloc(sizeof(X));` is valid C because you can implicitly cast from `void*` to `X*`, but it requires an explicit cast in C++.

Comment: I mean I have to merge this code with code generated by flex & bison. I'm generating C code out of flex and Bison since I know it is "more stable" code then C++. So I generate the code with flex and Bison using cygwin and then integrate the produced code in Visual Studio 2010. If I use the Visual Studio C++ compiler I have a lot of errors.